# How to setup aliased paths?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue-cli 2.8.1`.

Project initiated with `vue init webpack project`.

How to specify an alias and use it to resolve paths?

For instance, this is how it's done in webpack:

```
alias: {
  components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')
}
```

Then it's possible to make imports like this:

```
import Component from 'components/component'; // note there's no './' in the path
```

Comment: That looks like how you would do it, what's the issue?

Comment: @thanksd, there's no `webpack.config.js` in the downloaded starter

Comment: Is there not? `build/webpack.base.conf.js`

Comment: @thanksd, oh, I didn't look there. That's it! Thank you for the help, sir!